# vjs border on fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, video-streaming

I'm trying to remove those borders from fullscreen but without any kind of success, I looked for answers in the wiki but I didn't find anything about it

Here is  a part of my code:

```
    <div style="width: 99%; height: 50%; margin-left:0.5%;">
        <video id="player" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="video-js vjs-http-source-selector vjs-big-play-centered" preload="auto" data-setup='{"language":"fr"}' controls >
        </video>
    </div>
```

The java part:

```
var options = 
  {
    playbackRates : [0.5,1,1.5,2],
    userActions : {
    //hotkeys: 
},
    plugins: {
      httpSourceSelector:
      {
        default: 'auto'
      }
    },
  };
var player = videojs('player', options);
player.src("default.mp4");
player.play();
player.pause();
player.fluid(true);
player.fill(true);
player.src(dossier+'/'+fichier);
```

And here a picture as description of the issue:

[image: Borders on fullscreen]

Comment: "_The java part_" fyi, Javascript is _not_ Java. Where's the `php` part?

Comment: I don't understand your question, it's a part of a larger php page but actually I don't think that the issue comes from another part than vjs

Comment: You tagged this question with `php`, yet there is no `php` code.